# How to use cast in C?

Tags: c, variables, pointers, casting, void

I want to compare any data types and I don't know how to use a variable or constant, something like:

```
if ( *(var)v > *(var)(v+sizeof(int)) )
    //some instructions...
```

instead of:

```
if ( *(int*)v > *(int*)(v+sizeof(int)) )
    //some instructions...
```

where `var` can be an `int*`, `float*`, `char*` or any thing else and `v` is declared as

```
void* v;
```

Comment: Do you want to compare pointers or the values they point to? Do you know what the (typeless) void pointer really points to?

Comment: I want to compare values they point to. v points to int or float or structs and i know that type at the call of function where is the code above.

Comment: Just don't, casts are evil. And they are even more if you don't understand what you are doing. If you really need that, take a deep breadth and read on C's type system.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this in plain C, there is no "type inference". You can typecast any address (of an int, float etc.) to a `void*` but that's it. The comparison of the stuff that any `void*` points to, depends on the pointed data - and what you're trying to do is: compare two things without taking into account the data type.

For example, when you want to compare the following two bytes (binary notation):

```
1000 0000
```

and

```
0000 0001
```

What should your outcome be? That's impossible to tell. If they were signed 8-bit values (`char`) then the first value would be -1, the second would be 1 (so the second one is "bigger"). But if they were unsigned values (`unsigned char`) then the first one is 255 (so that one would be "bigger").

You'll have to include some type hint before you can perform the comparison. For example by casting two`void*`s to `char*` on one occasion, or to `unsigned char*` on another occasion.

Answer (score 3):

Using pointers to function and casting to `char *` for the pointer arithmetic, just as `qsort` does:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int cmpint(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    int a = *(int *)pa;
    int b = *(int *)pb;

    if (b > a) return -1;
    else return (a > b);
}

int cmpfloat(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    float a = *(float *)pa;
    float b = *(float *)pb;

    if (b > a) return -1;
    else return (a > b);
}


void fn(void *v, size_t size, int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    if (cmp(v, (char *)v + size) == 1) {
        /* some  instructions */
        puts("v is greater than v + 1");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int iarr[] = {5, 6};
    float farr[] = {7.f, 6.f};

    fn(iarr, sizeof(int), cmpint);
    fn(farr, sizeof(float), cmpfloat);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply dispatch based on the compared types:

```
switch (type) {
    case int_type: {
        int* v1 = p1;
        int* v2 = p2;
        return *v1 < *v2;
    }
    case float_type: {
        float* v1 = p1;
        float* v2 = p2;
        return *v1 < *v2;
    }
}
```

That should give you an idea how to compare these types. Extend this using checks for different types and adding some `const`. BTW: There is no cast being used here and that is IMHO good. There are implicit conversions from `void*` to `int*` or `float*` though.